# obtencion de datos asyncronos en react-native

Tags: react-native

Soy nueva con react-native, por lo que la pregunta puede ser un poco confusa. cuando ejecuto el codigo siempre recibo un array vacio(lista), creo que el render se ejecuta antes de obtener los datos de la api, si es asi como puedo obtener  primero los datos y luego renderizo, sino, alguna duda de que pueda ser?

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lista: [],
      area: "",
      empleado: "",
      servicio: "",
    };
  }

  async getProducto() {

    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://192.168.1.72:3000/");
      console.log(res.data);
      this.setState({ lista: res.data });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.lista.length > 0) {

      return (
        <View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {this.state.lista.map((item, i) => (
              <View key={i}>
                <Text>{item.area}</Text>
              </View>
            ))}

          </View>
        </View>
      );
    } else {

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>no tengo los datos</Text>
        </View>
      );

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido! En la medida que puedas, edita la pregunta pegando el codigo en lugar del texto. Nos va beneficiar a todos, creado una base de conocimiento mejor! (facilidad a los buscadores) Grácias!

Comment: No es necesario ese if de lenght de la lista y 2 returns con tener el map de la lista es suficiente, Tienes los ciclos de vida del componente , Did mount cuando se muestra en la ventana, luego did unmout cuando se saca de la ventana, y did update cada  vez que hay una actualizacion en el nodo al que pertecene o como este ligado como un ruta de actualizacion desde el padre hasta el ultimo hijo bisnieto.

Comment: Ejecuta tu codigo de obtener lista en componentDidMount  y cambia el state que contiene la lista para que actualize el componente al cambiar el estado se vuelve a renderizar. Es mejor que uses componentes funcionales para tener mejor optimizacion para cosas simples como esta.